# Python Logging: DEBUG level logs not logged when script autostarted from /etc/rc.local

Tags: python, logging, raspberry-pi, raspbian

On my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) The following code (test.py) logs both DEBUG and INFO log messages as expected in the log file '/home/pi/test/test.log' when launched from the console, but only logs the INFO log message when launched at startup (by the root user) from the /etc/rc.local file.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/pi/test/test.log',level=logging.DEBUG,\
      format='%(asctime)s -- %(module)s -- %(levelname)s -- %(message)s')

logging.debug('Debug error')
logging.info('INFO ERROR')
```

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code block you have specified should work perfectly fine and the debug message should go to the specified file

But remember that you can do `logging.basicConfig` only once for the python process. If you already done a `logging.basicConfig` from another module, or if you have configured the root logger in some other way, your config wont have any effect

Here is a snip from `help(logging.basicConfig)`

> basicConfig(**kwargs)
>       Do basic configuration for the logging system.
>
> ```
> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers
> configured. It is a convenience method intended for use by simple scripts
> to do one-shot configuration of the logging package.
> ```

Comment: But how do you explain I get the two logs when I launch the script from console and only the INFO one when it is autostarted from /etc/local.rc by the root user ?

Comment: If you are claiming that these exact 4 lines of code works differently for root user and non-root user, I dont have any clue

Comment: I'll check tonight, I may be wrong with the exact code I wrote. (I reported it here from memory). But yes, the code I wrote worked differently in the two use cases...

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, I was setting a handler at INFO level to my logger after having set the basicConfig... Stupid me. Forget ma question it works well...